# Saving images in a cycle

Tags: image, matlab, cycle

Im trying to figure out how to save multiple images in a cycle.

---

```
$piece1=[1,1,1;1,1,1;1,1,1];
$piece2=[0,1,0;1,1,1;1,0,1];
$piece3=[0,0,0;0,0,0;0,0,0];

$N=3;

$for i=1:N
$    (('piece' num2str(N)),('piece' num2str(N)),'jpeg');
$end
```

---

i cant make it working,
thanks for any help

Comment: Do not use postfixes in your variable names. Instead, learn cells and try to use them to hold your images if you really need to do so: http://bit.ly/vKwXC8

Answer (score 1):

```
piece1 = [1,1,1;1,1,1;1,1,1];
piece2 = [0,1,0;1,1,1;1,0,1];
piece3 = [0,0,0;0,0,0;0,0,0];

N=3;

for i=1:N
    imwrite(eval(['piece' num2str(i)]),['piece' num2str(i) '.jpeg']);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "Save" you mean saving it into a jpeg file, then the following code does it:

```
piece1=[1,1,1;1,1,1;1,1,1];
piece2=[0,1,0;1,1,1;1,0,1];
piece3=[0,0,0;0,0,0;0,0,0];

N = 3

for i=1:N
    piece = eval(sprintf('piece%d', i));
    file_name = sprintf('piece%d.jpg', i);
    imwrite(piece, file_name);
end
```

but in general your approach is not the best way of writing code in Matlab. You can use Cells for example:

```
piece{1}=[1,1,1;1,1,1;1,1,1];
piece{2}=[0,1,0;1,1,1;1,0,1];
piece{3}=[0,0,0;0,0,0;0,0,0];

for i=1:numel(piece)
    file_name = sprintf('piece%d.jpg', i);
    imwrite(piece{i}, file_name);
end
```